# Responsive Img within Jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my images in a jquery slider. The slider is working, but there are a couple of problems. I can have the images responsive, but when I remove the height property, the content below shoots up into the slider. So I then add a height value, but the images become distorted when re-sizing the window. I was wondering if you can see where I am going wrong.

HTML

```
         <div id="indexSlider" class="indexImg">
            <div><img class="indexImg" src="imgs//test/test1.jpg"></div>
            <div><img class="indexImg" src="imgs/test/test2.jpg"></div>
            <div><img class="indexImg" src="imgs//test/test3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .indexImg {
height: 45rem;
width: 100%;    
}


 #indexSlider div {
position:absolute;
z-index: 0;
}

 #indexSlider div.previous {
z-index: 1;
}

 #indexSlider div.current {
z-index: 2;
}
```

JQUERY

```
 $(function() {
        // create the image rotator
        setInterval("rotateImages()", 2000);
    });

    function rotateImages() {
        var oCurPhoto = $('#indexSlider div.current');
        var oNxtPhoto = oCurPhoto.next();
        if (oNxtPhoto.length == 0)
            oNxtPhoto = $('#indexSlider div:first');

        oCurPhoto.removeClass('current').addClass('previous');
        oNxtPhoto.css({ opacity: 0.0 }).addClass('current')
                .animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 700,
                            function() {
                                oCurPhoto.removeClass('previous');
                            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using img tag you can add image as a background to the div

```
<div id="indexSlider">
  <div class="indexImg" style="background-image: url('imgs/test/test1.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="indexImg" style="background-image: url('imgs/test/test2.jpg');"></div>
  <div class="indexImg" style="background-image: url('imgs/test/test3.jpg');"></div>
</div>
```

And on the css

```
.indexImg {
  height: 45rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat:none;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center; 
}
```

Comment: does the slider work as expected now? add position:relative to #indexSlider and set height of it..